# Redistribute elements of an array into multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I intend to create a dataframe from an array - with the element of the array sequentially distributed to multiple columns.

ex:

```
var A = Array(1,2,4,21,2,4,34,2,24,2,4,24,5,8,4,2,1,1)
var B = sc.parallelize(A.grouped(3).toList).map(Tuple1(_)).toDF("values")
```

Above results in

```
|     values|
+-----------+
|  [1, 2, 4]|
| [21, 2, 4]|
|[34, 2, 24]|
| [2, 4, 24]|
|  [5, 8, 4]|
|  [2, 1, 1]|
+-----------+
```

But I need these 3 elements in 3 different columns.

Please suggest a solution that doesn't hard code for 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that you are creating Tuple1 which is a single element. Had you used a x=>Tuple3(x(0), x(1), x(2)) that would have solved it for the case of 3.

If you do not want to hardcode, you can do something like this:

```
def addColumns(num: Int, origDF: DataFrame) {
    var df = origDF
    for {
       x <- 0 to num
    } {
      df = df.withColumn(s"col_$x", udf((y: Seq[Int]) => y(x))($"values"))
    }
    df
}
```

this will extract the relevant columns (you might also want to drop the original values).